# AWS Cognito expired access token

Tags: next.js, amazon-cognito, next-auth

In my application I have used `aws cognito` with `next auth` for user auth.

In the `jwt callback` that I have from api next-auth I receive an access token, which is then saved and sent to the client side. There, I save it in local storage and, among other things, I send it to my api which checks if it is correct.

The problem is that after an hour the access token expires and does not get a new one (always next-auth gives me old value). Has anyone had a similar flow and knows how to manage a session refresh? I will add that I am not automatically logged out because `next-auth` is managing it underneath, but it does not return the value of the new access token to me.

Do you have any ways how to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a workaround that would take the least effort to solve this quickly. Amazon Cognito contains 3 kinds of tokens, the `ID Token`, `Access Token` and `Refresh Token`.

From the Amazon Cognito console, you can increase the validity of the token you're dealing with from there. A good idea is to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712872/how-to-modify-expiry-time-of-the-access-and-identity-tokens-for-aws-cognito-user) answer.

Albeit you might need a couple of methods to assert security and robustness.

Comment: Arka Mukherjee thx for your answer. Do you know why I cannot receive valid `access token` if old one is expired ? It's strange for me. Do you suggest to me use `Id Token` instead of `Access token` ?