# Approach for logging an user out of AWS Cognito after 20 minutes of inactivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

If I want the user to be logged out after 20 minutes of inactivity - is this approach valid?

1. Set up Post Authentication Lambda Trigger
2. In the Lambda listen
   for API calls
3. If 20 minutes has passed and no API calls have been
   made then call `RevokeToken`

Is this approach going to allow me to log out the user after 20 minutes of inactivity?

Comment: Related: [Best approach for limiting Amazon Cognito concurrent logins](https://repost.aws/questions/QUvCK68PkCSAaMS9fcNI1k0w/best-approach-for-limiting-amazon-cognito-concurrent-logins).

Comment: This sounds backwards to me. Would you instead set the token expiry to 20-30 minutes and have a refresh token that gets used if the client is active : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-refresh-token.html. Custom token expiration : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712872/how-to-modify-expiry-time-of-the-access-and-identity-tokens-for-aws-cognito-user

Comment: Thank you for this info @lloyd however this doesn't deal with the tracking of user inactivity. Also as stated in the documentation, the minimum you can set expiry to is 60minutes.

Comment: @i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i Have you resolved your problem?